# Could OpenWrt run on barebox?

Tags: bootloader, openwrt

1. Could OpenWrt run on barebox
2. Is there a portable application framework on top of uboot/barebox? So my source code is indepent from the low-level hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Absolutely possible. I've been using barebox as a main bootloader for imx25 SoC. There is no barebox in a public packages though(I've never met it), but you can build your own "bootloader-barebox" package.
   Just follow these links:
   https://vivekian2.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/building-your-own-package-for-openwrt/
   [http://prplfoundation.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenWrt_package_for_a_web_page](https://vivekian2.wordpress.com/2007/03/28/building-your-own-package-for-openwrt/)
2. I'm not sure about framework, but you probably know that you can create an application. http://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootStandalone

Here is an example of Makefile for barebox:

```
#
# Copyright (C) 2013 OpenWrt.org
#
# This is free software, licensed under the GNU General Public License v2.
# See /LICENSE for more information.
#

include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk
include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/kernel.mk

PKG_NAME:=barebox
PKG_VERSION:=0.1
PKG_RELEASE:=0

PKG_BUILD_DIR:=$(KERNEL_BUILD_DIR)/$(PKG_NAME)-$(BUILD_VARIANT)/$(PKG_NAME)
PKG_SOURCE:=$(PKG_NAME).tar.bz2
PKG_SOURCE_PROTO:=git
PKG_SOURCE_URL:=GIT-URL
PKG_SOURCE_VERSION:=93aeafd04365cdd5dcb958cc6982c672163154ee
PKG_SOURCE_SUBDIR:=$(PKG_NAME)
PKG_MD5SUM:=
PKG_TARGETS:=bin

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define barebox/Default
  TITLE:=
  CONFIG:=
  IMAGE:=
endef

define Package/barebox/template
define Package/barebox-$(1)
  SECTION:=boot
  CATEGORY:=Boot Loaders
  TITLE:=$(2)
  DEPENDS:=@TARGET_$(1)
  URL:=http://localhost/
  DEFAULT:=y if (TARGET_$(1)_Default)
  VARIANT:=$(1)
endef
endef

define BuildBareboxPackage
    $(eval $(barebox/Default))
    $(eval $(barebox/$(1)))
    $(call Package/barebox/template,$(1),$(TITLE))
endef

define barebox/imx
  TITLE:=Barebox for the imx.
endef

BAREBOXS:=imx


ifdef BUILD_VARIANT
    $(eval $(call barebox/$(BUILD_VARIANT)))
    BAREBOX_CONFIG:=$(if $(CONFIG),$(CONFIG),$(BUILD_VARIANT))
    BAREBOX_IMAGE:=$(if $(IMAGE),$(IMAGE),openwrt-$(BOARD)-$(BUILD_VARIANT)-barebox.bin)
endif

define Build/Prepare
    $(call Build/Prepare/Default)
endef

define Build/Configure
    $(CP) ./barebox-config $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/.config
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR) \
        CROSS_COMPILE=$(TARGET_CROSS) ARCH=arm 
endef

define Package/barebox/install/template
define Package/barebox-$(1)/install
    $(CP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/barebox.bin $(BIN_DIR)/$(2)
endef
endef

$(foreach u,$(BAREBOXS), \
     $(eval $(call Package/barebox/install/template,$(u),openwrt-$(BOARD)-$(u)-barebox.bin)) \
)

$(foreach u,$(BAREBOXS), \
    $(eval $(call BuildBareboxPackage,$(u))) \
    $(eval $(call BuildPackage,barebox-$(u))) \
)
```